# Unable to browse internet after connect to OpenVPN

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, dns, openvpn, amazon-web-services

I've tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5073249/openvpn-unable-to-browse-internet-after-connect-to-openvpn) because my problem is exactly the same with it, but it does not work.

I used [this script](https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install) to construct my OpenVPN server, and it worked normally for a long time. But one day it suddenly failed, I even don't know why.

So the current situation is, upon connection, I can ping 10.8.0.1 with no problem, but I can not even visit Google.

And the server can visit Google normally.

My OpenVPN server, ubuntu, was constructed in AWS, and `Server.conf` was as followed.

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.31.0.2"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
crl-verify crl.pem
```

172.31.0.2 is DNS assigned by AWS. So far I've tried the following moves, and not fixed.

1. Change `dhcp-option DNS 172.31.0.2` to `8.8.8.8`
2. Run `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

A weird thing is that, I cannot ping my DNS(172.31.0.2/8.8.8.8) upon connection, even `ipconfig` shows my DNS is 172.31.0.2/8.8.8.8(I've tried them both).

The following is client config, client is Windows 10.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
remote <domain name> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

I've run out of ideas, please help me!

Comment: What do you mean the script suddenly failed? What actually happened? Does your server and client have correct IPs that are within the range you expect for the VPN connection?

Comment: Suddenly failed is, I had used this server for a long time, and it's fine, but one day after connecting it, I found that this problem occurred, I even don't know the reason yet.

Comment: Server and client have correct IPs.
Server has IP that Amazon assigned, and it can connect to any websites normally.
Client get its IP by DHCP, and use 10.8.0.3 as preferred. Seem pretty well.

Comment: What are the route settings before/after you connect the VPN? Can you ping well-known Internet sites by address (8.8.8.8 for instance)?

Comment: My computer is connected to routers, so route settings is allied to leaf router, and DNS of root router is 8.8.8.8.

Comment: Before connecting VPN, I can ping 8.8.8.8 without problem. But after connecting to VPN, it shows that my DNS is 8.8.8.8, but I cannot ping it. This is weird, I can barely understand.